# How to run the project in lite version

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

Hi friends i am new iphone developer my project is previous is done in x code 3.2.1 earlier version but presently i was use that project in x code 3.2.1 but this kind of error is occurred what is the reason please help me.
The Error is:

`The project “Irehab.x code project was saved with a newer version of X code than this one. This version of X code might or might not be able to open the project. Even if the project can be opened, information might be lost. Do you still want to try opening the project?`

Comment: what u want to say that?

Comment: when I click open button project is project is not working some files missing what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

If u want to run any application of previous version of xcode in new version then click on project tab and select edit project settings. You get new window in which u change the base sdk type and select latest know ios. After that you again click on project tab then click on edit target settings and again change base sdk settings and set as latest known ios. After that in editor windoe change base sdk simulator.
It will work .

Comment: i was change all above mention suggestion but

Comment: The above mention error occurred when i click open button some files missing project not working what we do please help me.

Comment: click on group and files then in right side u see have add ur project file with target?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to open with an older version of Xcode a project that was created (or updated to) a newer version of Xcode.

While you can open a older project with the latest Xcode version, the opposite is not always true and the message is telling you that.

One option you have is trying to use the project as it is (i.e., ignoring the warning you get), and try to fix the issues you have; though, possibly the best option you have is creating the project again with the Xcode version you want to use (i.e., creating an empry project and copy over to it files, nibs, create targets, add frameworks, etc.)